# How to do automoving from one page to another page and back to first page where pagination is there in table in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I am trying to add automoving with pagination for table in HTML.
For eg i have table with 100 rows and then i am doing pagination for it with 10 records on one page.So there will be 10 pages with 10 records each.
I nedd to do it automatically so that user dont have to specifically click on the page and see.

I used paging.js

with below code

```
  <style type="text/css">
  .paging-nav {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 2px;
  }
  .paging-nav a {
  margin: auto 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  background: #91b9e6;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  }
  .paging-nav .selected-page {
  background: #187ed5;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
  .paging-nav,
  #tableData {
  'width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  </style>

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file').paging({limit:10});
  });
```

Here file is id of table which is to be paginated. How can i go about changing page of table automatically? All answers are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for how to start with it..
***beware this is just an example, do not copy! for your own protection***

```js
//create
el = $("<table></table>");
for (var i = 1; i !== 100; i++) {
  el.append("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>buuurp</td></tr>");
}
el.data("intStart", 1);
el.appendTo("body");


//fuction
function showRow(j = 10) { //default var j = 10; you can call showRow(50) for 50 as example
  var i = $("table").data().intStart; //grabs data that hold the number of currect first element to view
  $("tr").hide();
  // hides all
  $("tr").filter(function(index) {
    return index >= i - 1 && index < i + j - 1; //jquery has 0-9 we count in 1-10 so -1
  }).show(); //shows the one needed
  $("table").data().intStart += j; //addes 'j' to the counter
  if ($("table").data().intStart > $("table").children("tr").lenght) {
    clearInterval(timer); //if we reach the end we can kill this
  }
}

showRow();
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  showRow();
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks i got some idea how to do that